# How do I properly implement multiprocessing with Openstreetmap when trying to find the nearest edge from a (latitude,longitude) point?

Tags: python, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, gis, openstreetmap

My goal is to use (latitude, longitude) data of car locations in Delaware to find out the road type they're on from the OpenStreetMap API.  I need to go through 470,000 rows, and right now, it's taking 30 seconds/iteration.  This is too long, and I need to either get the time per iteration down or get the multiprocessing to work.  This is my attempt at multiprocessing:

```
import osmnx as ox
import networkx as nx
import pickle
import pandas as pd
import time
import os
import pdb
import numpy as np
from tqdm import tqdm
from multiprocessing import Pool
import multiprocessing
from functools import partial
import copy



def overall_func(args):

    network,row=args
    local_network = copy.deepcopy(network)  # Create a deep copy for each process
    latitude, longitude = row["end_latitude"], row["end_longitude"]
    print(latitude,longitude)

    # Skip the row if start_latitude or start_longitude is NaN
    if pd.isna(latitude) or pd.isna(longitude):
        return None

    def find_nearest_edge_coordinates(network,lat, long):
        .

        #start=time.time()
    
        # Find the nearest edge to the given latitude and longitude
        nearest_edge = ox.nearest_edges(network, long, lat, return_dist=False)[:2]
    
        #end = time.time()
        #print('time for one nearest edges calculation: ',end-start)

        """
        # Edges below is a dictionary.   The keys of edges dictionary are each node in the graph.  
        The values for each node are a dictionary of dictionaries.
        There is one nested dictionary for each outgoing edge from the source node.  
        For example, if node 1 connects to 4 other nodes, there are 4 edges/road segments with information to display.
        The edges dictionary key '1' would have 4 nested dictionaries.  Each of these 4 nested dictionaries
        would contain information about the edge such as road type, length, geometry, etc. """
        edges = network.edges.keys()._mapping.data()._adjdict
        """Use nearest edge, which was obtained earlier, to filter the edges dictionary for the nearest road segment
        and extract the road type"""

        try:
            edge_coords = edges[nearest_edge[0]][nearest_edge[1]][0]['highway']
        except:
            edge_coords = None
            print('None')

        return edge_coords

    # retrieve the nearest edge/roadtype from the already loaded graph  
    highway_tag = find_nearest_edge_coordinates(local_network, latitude, longitude)
    return highway_tag
 


if __name__ == '__main__':
    
  multiprocessing.freeze_support()
  #Load the previously loaded network
  with open('C:\\Users\\VivekReddy\\OneDrive - Aioi Nissay Dowa Insurance Services USA Corporation\\Desktop\\delaware_net.pickle','rb') as f:
      delaware_network = pickle.load(f)


  input_file = "RoadTypeStuff/TS500_Delaware.csv"
  output_file = "RoadTypeStuff/TS500_Delaware_Highway.csv"

  df = pd.read_csv(input_file)
  print('Loaded Input File')

    
  pool = Pool(processes=5)
  print('started pool')

  b = pool.map(overall_func, df.iloc[:5,:].iterrows())
  print(b)
```

This is the error message I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 125, in worker
    result = (True, func(*args, **kwds))
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 48, in mapstar
    return list(map(*args))
  File "C:\Users\VivekReddy\Downloads\testing.py", line 59, in overall_func
    highway_tag = find_nearest_edge_coordinates(local_network, latitude, longitude)
  File "C:\Users\VivekReddy\Downloads\testing.py", line 33, in find_nearest_edge_coordinates
    nearest_edge = ox.nearest_edges(network, long, lat, return_dist=False)[:2]
  File "C:\Users\VivekReddy\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\osmnx\distance.py", line 293, in nearest_edges
    geoms = utils_graph.graph_to_gdfs(G, nodes=False)["geometry"]
  File "C:\Users\VivekReddy\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\osmnx\utils_graph.py", line 41, in graph_to_gdfs
    crs = G.graph["crs"]
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'graph'
"""

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\VivekReddy\Downloads\testing.py", line 82, in <module>
    b = pool.map(overall_func, df.iloc[:5,:].iterrows())
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 367, in map
    return self._map_async(func, iterable, mapstar, chunksize).get()
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 774, in get
    raise self._value
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'graph'
```

There seems to be an error in this function ox.nearest_edges.  Would anyone know why?

Comment: It appears that while iterating over the DataFrame with `iterrows()`, the index is being passed as the `network` argument in the `overall_func(args)`, and the actual row contents are being unpacked as `row`. This is because you're directly passing the output of `iterrows()` to `pool.map(overall_func, df.iloc[:5,:].iterrows())`.